# How do you choose which game you want to play in Crash Bandicoot N Sane Trilogy?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

How is it possible to select which game out of the 3 available you want to play in N Sane Trilogy? Does each game first need to be completed separately, at which point the next game in the series is unlocked for play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you start the game, you land on screen where you can choose freely any game of trilogy. 
I barely started first one but it let me to play second or third game. Tested on Steam version but I expect all versions to be similar.

[image: Crash Bandicoot NSane trilogy initial screen]

Comment: This is also the case with the Switch version.

Comment: There are no restrictions on which game you can play.